# i really cant find my problem.. but my problem is that i have something duplicated in my tuple

Tags: django, django-models

the error is :

> ERRORS: <class 'registerapp.admin.UserAdminConfig'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[1][1]'. <class 'registerapp.admin.UserAdminConfig'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[2][1]'. 
>
> btw I have to inform that I have used mobileNumber as unique=True in my model

```
from django.contrib import admin
from registerapp.models import Members
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class UserAdminConfig(UserAdmin):
    search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'mobileNumber',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'name', 'mobileNumber', 'nationalCode',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    list_display = ('email', 'familyName', 'mobileNumber', 'nationalCode', 'is_active', 'is_staff')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'familyName')}),
        ('User information', {'fields': ('email', 'name', 'familyName', 'mobileNumber', 'password', 'nationalCode')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'groups')}),

    )

    add_fieldsets = (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'name', 'familyName', 'mobileNumber', 'password', 'nationalCode')
    })


admin.site.register(Members, UserAdminConfig)
```

**my model**

```
class customMemberManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, password, nationalCode, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('YOU MUST ENTER VALID EMAIL')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, mobileNumber=mobileNumber, name=name, familyName=familyName, password=password,
                          nationalCode=nationalCode, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, password, nationalCode, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be is_staff set to True')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be is_superuser set to True')
        return self.create_user(email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, password, nationalCode, **other_fields)


class Members(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Members'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    familyName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    nationalCode = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    mobileNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = customMemberManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobileNumber'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nationalCode', 'familyName', 'name', 'email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.__str__()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error say, you have duplicate fields in fieldsets.
First fieldset "None" has "name" and "familyName", second fieldset "User Information" has "name" and "familyName" again.

Try removing "name" and "familyName" from first or second fieldset